# Deal with residue messages before actor restart

Tags: java, akka

I have an `UntypedActor` running with a `PinnedDispatcher` that when started, tries to do *one and only one* heavy task *T*.

To make the actor more responsive, the task *T* is chopped into many sequential sub-tasks *T<sub>1</sub>* ... *T<sub>n</sub>*, and each sub-task handler sends `self()` a new message to continue next sub-task:

```java
@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    try {
        MethodUtils.invokeMethod(this, "handleMessage", message);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        unhandled(message);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void handleMessage(T1 message) {
    doTask1();
    getSelf().tell(new T2(), getSelf());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void handleMessage(T2 message) {
    doTask2();
    getSelf().tell(new T3(), getSelf());
}
```

The problem is, if the actor crashes upon a message from other actors, it is likely some residue message (e.g. `T3`) will remain in the mailbox after restart.

Is there any way to make this kind of actor in a clean initial state after restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `getContext().become()`, we can build a state machine. When the actor is in its initial state, it only expects one kind of message to start processing (`T1` in this case). Before this message is received, just ignore any other messages.